# Challenge JavaScript for kids. Chapter 6. What is correct answer

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

In the book: "JavaScript for kids" in the end of chapter 6 there is this challenge to create random string generator, from letters taken out of var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
In the book autor ask specifically to use  WHILE loop which I faild to do.

Than I found out that correct answer required FOR loop and goes as follow:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var randomString = "";
var stringLength = 6;

for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
  randomString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
}

console.log(randomString);
```

my question: is it possible to do the same with the WHILE loop?

Comment: Every `for` loop can be written as a `while` loop.

Comment: Yes, you can always do it. Just separate out the different parts of the for loop. `var i = 0; while (i < stringLength) { i++; }`

Comment: or: `while(randomString.length < stringLength) { // stuff }`

Comment: Thank you for help! That answer my question !

Comment: I wonder what person thought this question "shows research effort".

Comment: I am sorry, I was looking for the answer but when you are new at sth right questions are not easy to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Every `for` loop can be written as a `while` loop. In general your `for` loop descriptor has three expressions: an initialisation, a condition and some sort of increment. Let's call these `a`, `b` and `c`.

Then this:

```
for (a; b; c) {
    // ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
a;
while (b) {
    // ...
    c;
}
```

NB: There can be subtle differences when `let` is used.

Comment: Thank you, it gives me better understanding where I was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but you'd have to manage increasing the loop-counter yourself:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < stringLength) {
  randomString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
  i++;
}
```

IMHO, a `for` loop is more appropriate here.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can check on randomString.length

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that if you want a `while` to behave the same as a `for` the `i++;` should be the last executed statement of the loop

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do the same, if you implement it the right way. Check on randomString.length and compare it with your chosen stringLength.

```js
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var randomString = "";
var stringLength = 6;

while(randomString.length < stringLength){
  randomString += alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
}

console.log(randomString);
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly it.